# document.head and document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] strange behavior

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out what's wrong with this code.  After defining a script like this:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://example.com/file.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.onload = function(){
    //code to execute after script loads
}
```

I then have the following line:

```
(document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]).appendChild(script);
```

For some reason, I am getting very odd inconsistent behavior where it seems that the `onload` function is being called before the `file.js` is actually loaded. There are variables contained in `file.js` that I use in the `onload` function, and every so often, the function executes before those variables are defined according to the error console.

If I change the last line to:

```
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Or

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

The problem seems to go away.

The problem also goes away if I assign it to a variable before appending:

```
var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
head.appendChild(script);
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's caused by a missing semicolon:

```
script.onload = function(){

}; // Add this semicolon and it will be fixed
```

Without that semicolon the interpreter parses your next set of parenthesis as though you are immediately invoking that anonymous function and then attempting to call `appendChild` on that function's return value. It's interpreted like so:

```
script.onload = (function(){
    //code to execute after script loads
}(document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0])).appendChild(script);
```

Which will certainly throw an error ***after*** executing your anonymous function (unless that function actually returns an object which has an appendChild function).

Comment: Wow, that is amazing thank you so much. I would have never figured that out.